# npm install with --no-package-lock flag - is existing package-lock.json used?

Tags: npm

From the [npm 5 doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> The --no-package-lock argument will prevent npm from creating a package-lock.json file.

Does an `npm install` with `--no-package-lock` follows the `package-lock.json` (if already exists) deterministic install / nested locked versions ? Or does it completly ignore it ?

Answer (score 22):

Answer from the [@npm_support](https://twitter.com/npm_support/status/884842423159054340):

> Using `--no-package-lock` skips the package-lock. It is neither read nor written as if the package-lock feature did not exist.

So the `package-lock.json` file isn't used at all when the `--no-package-lock` is on.

Comment: There are some additional details on the [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For deterministic install you must have an `package-lock.json` and use `npm ci`. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci

> This command is similar to npm install, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment -- or any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies.